# android-youtube-player change videoId programmatically

Tags: android

I'm using PierfrancescoSoffritti's android-youtube-player so this is my question:

How can I change the videoId programmatically in kotlin (from the MainActivity)?

Maybe it's just because I'm new to android studio so I don't really understand this, but I noticed that in the layout.xml file all the attributes that I can change by calling apply on the view like this (below) are android:attribute, and the videoId is app:videoId.

`val video = findViewById<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView>(R.id.youtube_player_view){ video.videoId = "Id" }`

this is what I have tried so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the library and it is listed in the documentation that you can change video id as follows:

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);

youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
  @Override
  public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
    String videoId = "S0Q4gqBUs7c"; //change according to your need
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
  }
});
```

this can be translated to kotlin as:

```
val youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view)
getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView)

    youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
        fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
            val videoId = "S0Q4gqBUs7c" //change according to your need
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0)
        }
    })
```

you can use the above code to change your video id programmatically. just replace the video id section with your id. Hope this helps. Happy coding!!